# Zuul gateway not able to connect to Eureka service registry under Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

When I start Eureka and Zuul independently via Spring-Boot runnable jar files, everything seems to work fine. But when I try to run each in a Docker container and connect them with Docker-Compose, the Zuul gateway is not able to find the Eureka server.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'

services:

 eureka-serviceregistry:
  container_name: serviceregistry
  build: ./ServiceRegistry
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
  hostname: serviceregistry
  environment:
    eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka/

 zuul-edgeservice:
  container_name: gateway
  build: ./ServiceGateway
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  hostname: gateway
  environment:
      eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone: http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka/
```

Eureka Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Spring Boot app.jar to Container
COPY /build/libs/ServiceRegistry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/ServiceRegistry.jar

EXPOSE 8761

# Fire up our Spring Boot app by default
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/local/ServiceRegistry.jar" ]
```

Eureka application.properties:

```
server.port=8761

spring.application.name=EurekaServiceRegistry

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=EurekaServiceRegistry

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=INFO
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=INFO
```

Eureka Spring-Boot class:

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class QQServiceRegistry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QQServiceRegistry.class, args);
    }
}
```

Zuul Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add Spring Boot app.jar to Container
COPY /build/libs/ServiceGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/ServiceGateway.jar

EXPOSE 8080

# Fire up our Spring Boot app by default
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/local/ServiceGateway.jar" ]
```

Zuul application.properties:

```
zuul.routes.auth.path=/enterprise_service/**
zuul.routes.auth.service-id=ENTERPRISE_SERVICE
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Zuul Spring-Boot class:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceGateway {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceGateway.class, args);
    }
}
```

Root build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    artifactory {
        contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
            defaults {
                publications ('mavenJava')
            }
        }
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
                maven = true
            }
        }
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }

    artifactoryPublish {
        dependsOn assemble
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.M8'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    }

   bootJar {
        launchScript()
    }
}
```

Eureka sub-project gradle file:

```
group = 'my.company.service.infrastructure.registry'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server')
}
```

Zuul sub project gradle file:

```
group = 'my.company.service.infrastructure.gateway'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
}
```

And in the Zuul log, this error pattern over and over as it tries to register with Eureka:

> 2018-04-11 15:38:20.136  INFO 6 --- [nfoReplicator-0] >com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/gateway: >registering service...
>   2018-04-11 15:38:20.139 ERROR 6 --- [nfoReplicator-0] >c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
>
> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: >Connection refused (Connection refused)
>     at >com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4>Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
>     at >com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEn>codingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFil>ter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client->1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
>     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~>>[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
>     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~>[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
>     at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) >~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.re>gister(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56) ~[eureka-client->1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.ex>ecute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpCli>ent.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client->1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.ex>ecute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.ex>ecuteOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client->1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.ex>ecute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.ex>ecute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.exec>ute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.ex>ecute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.exec>ute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) >[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:10>4) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201>(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Schedu>ledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~>[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:>206) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~>[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~>[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory>.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(Defaul>tClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~>[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdap>ter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDir>ector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirect>or.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.jav>a:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.jav>a:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.jav>a:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/:4.5.5]
>     at >com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4>Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
>     ... 29 common frames omitted
>
> 2018-04-11 15:38:20.140  WARN 6 --- [nfoReplicator-0] >c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with >message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   2018-04-11 15:38:20.140  WARN 6 --- [nfoReplicator-0] >com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/gateway - >registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
>
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute >request on any known server
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.exec>ute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.ex>ecute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.exec>ute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) >~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:10>4) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201>(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Schedu>ledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
>
> 2018-04-11 15:38:20.141  WARN 6 --- [nfoReplicator-0] >c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the >instance info replicator
>
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute >request on any known server
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.exec>ute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.ex>ecute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.exec>ute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.regi>ster(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:829) >~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at >com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:10>4) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar!/:1.8.6]
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201>(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Schedu>ledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at >java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) >[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
>
> 2018-04-11 15:38:50.043 ERROR 6 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] >c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was bad YAML syntax.

The following docker-compose.yml works. Note the environment sections.

```
version: '3.6'

services:

  eureka-serviceregistry:
    container_name: serviceregistry
    build: ./ServiceRegistry
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    hostname: serviceregistry
    environment:
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka

  zuul-edgeservice:
    container_name: gateway
    build: ./ServiceGateway
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    hostname: gateway
    environment:
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing with spring.application.name=**serviceregistry** 
eureka.instance.hostname=**serviceregistry** in application.properties under eureka server.